# When user hits a certain route, another one shows up in my ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My application is showing this weird behavior. Let's say that the link for it is like this:

```
http://<serverhere>
```

But when the users use this link, another one shows up:

```
http://<serverhere>/Access/Login/?login=<somevalue>
```

And as I don't have this route mapped, I get an error

> Resource Not Found

Here's my route config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(name: "Access",
                url: "Access/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "Index" }
               );

routes.MapRoute(name: "AccessIndex",
                url: "Access/Index",
                defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "Index" }
               );

routes.MapRoute(name: "Main",
                url: "Main/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index" }
               );

routes.MapRoute(name: "MainIndex",
                url: "Main/Index",
                defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index" }
               );

// padrão
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );
```

And here is my `AccessController`:

```
public class AccessController: BaseController
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            LimparSession();
            RepositorioAcesso repositorio = new RepositorioAcesso();
            string login = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split(new[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].ToLower();
            Acesso acesso = repositorio.RecuperarAcesso(login, false);

            if (acesso == null)
            {
                ViewBag.mensagem = "User Not Found";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Access", new { @login = login });
            }
        }

        private void LimparSession()
        {
            Session.Clear();
        }

        private RedirectToRouteResult Login(string login)
        {
            //Get info and then redirect

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Principal");
        }
}
```

What can I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: It is right there in your code `return RedirectToAction("Login", "Access", new { @login = login });`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Do i have to turn this method to public? Or map it in my route config? If so, how can i map it?

Comment: You would first need to explain what it is you are actually trying to do. The logical flow of your current code is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should improve you access logic.

```
Acesso acesso = repositorio.RecuperarAcesso(login, false);

if (acesso == null)
{
    ViewBag.mensagem = "User Not Found";
    return View();
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Access", new { @login = login });
}
```

The logic behind this simple conditional block is that if the user an access for the site he is shown "User Not Found" page, otherwise is being redirected to a login page. If you're familiar enough with how MVC works, you can see that `Access/Login/?login=<somevalue>` route is calling the `Login` action method of the `Access` Controller, providing a value for the `login` argument, which is exactly what you've instructed it to do within the `else` block of the conditional statement.

Comment: I removed the "Login" method and put its logic inside the Index method. I guess that did the trick.